# How to list another account in the Windows 8 UAC prompt

Tags: windows-8, uac

At work, I was recently upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro.

I've been using the Win 8 UAC prompt for installing software a lot, but I have to keep typing in the full admin name: “[machineName]\AdminAccount”. In Windows 7, the UAC prompt listed other accounts besides the currently logged in user ("Looking for credential tiles..."). In Win 8.1, I see just the current user.

So how do I add an account to always show in the Windows 8.1 UAC prompt?

Comment: I believe this is as designed. If you have the admin login, you could just turn off UAC or lower the notification settings  until you are done installing software...

Comment: Yeah, I think the best option is to sign in as the admin to install all the software, or lower UAC.

Comment: Another easy option: temporarily set current user account to admin. However, I'm required to normally operate on a non-admin level (security purposes), so in the end I'm still left with keying in the full account info for day-to-day work.